# how to select the row which comes first alphabetically and integer wise?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table:

```
ID | title1 | year1 | title2 | year2 | title3 | year3
5  |  ghost | 2006  | runner | 2007  | alpha  | 2008
5  |  ghost | 2006  | runner | 2007  | beta   | 2008
6  |  Fight | 2007  | guard  | 2008  | Jack   | 2009
6  |  Steam | 2010  | Pilot  | 2011  | save   | 2012
```

So I need a query that returns:

```
ID | title1 | year1 | title2 | year2 | title3 | year3
5  | ghost  | 2006  | runner | 2007  | alpha  | 2008
6  | Steam  | 2010  | Pilot  | 2011  | save   | 2012
```

Best way of going about this? I was thinking of joining the table by itself and doing some operations but haven't had any luck.

the condition is that if ID has two different titles under the same year, then pick the title that comes first alphabetically, else pick the largest 3 consecutive years

Comment: Could you state which by which columns do you need it sorted? Is it title1 and ID?

Comment: How you chose `alpha` instead of `beta` in first row.

Comment: title1, title2, title3 and year1, year2, year3

Comment: Why Fight is not in your returns

Comment: I return alpha because alpha comes first before beta alphabetically

Comment: @shA.t because the condition is that if ID has two different titles under the same year, then pick the title that comes first alphabetically, else pick the largest 3 consecutive years

Comment: I'm not sure if postgress has it, but on sql server I'd use this in a CTE or derived table and add this to the select column list: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by ID ORDER BY Title1) AS RowID ` then in the outer query you can filter on `WHERE RowID=1`

Comment: Please update the question. `else pick the largest 3 consecutive years` is unclear, does not correspond to your example, either. `title` is unclear: there are three different title columns.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter apparently the person who answered my question understood it. Also how does that not correspond to my example?

Comment: "The *row with the* largest three consecutive rows". I understood 3 rows when I read it. And `title` is obviously unclear. Could you just clarify?

Comment: If it helps, ID is an actor, titles are the movie titles that the actor was involved in. title1 is when movie1 was released, title2 is when movie2 was released and title3 is when movie3 was released.  Select the row (grouped by ID) with the  latest 3 consecutive years and if the year is the same, choose the title of the movie which comes first alphabetically.

Comment: The point is to *update* the question. Not many read convoluted comments. The question should be presented in a clear fashion. And *always* add your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Window Function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html), and select the first row in each `id` group:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER ( PARTITION BY id
      ORDER BY title1, title2, title3, year1 DESC, year2 DESC, year3 DESC ) AS row_number
  FROM foo
) x
WHERE x.row_number = 1;
```

Comment: should the the highest 3 consecutive years so if ID 1 has year 1 = 2009 year 2 = 2010 year 3 =2011 and he also has another row which has year 1 = 2010, year 2 = 2011, year 3 =2012. It should choose the latter of the two rows.

Comment: Missed that bit when I first read it! I've added a fix to sort the years descending, so that you'll get the largest first.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, `DISTINCT ON` is typically simpler and faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id, title1, title2, title3, year1 DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Assuming that `pick the title that comes first alphabetically` means to order by `title1` first, then `title2`, then `title3`.
Assuming that `year1`, `year2` and `year3` are *always* consecutive. So, sorting by either one of them does the trick.

`NULLS LAST` is only needed if `year1` can be NULL:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Details for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)